# Vanilla Settings Errors

Tags: php, include, warnings, forum, fatal-error

http://reps.michebagshows.com/forums/

Recently, our customer forums popped up with this slew of errors from settings.php in the Vanilla forum software. We have no idea how this happened, as none of the files have been modified for months. Todd over at Vanilla suggested that the permissions changed, but those haven't been touched either. He then sent me to another user for help, who hasn't even logged in in a week.

How can this be fixed? We're getting quite a few complaints about it because the forums are the way our customers trade and discuss our product among each other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Example errors:

```
Warning: include_once(/path/to/vanilla/appg/database.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 244
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/vanilla/appg/database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 244
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/database/file.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 245
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/database/file.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 245
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 246
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 246
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.Database.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 247
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.Database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 247
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.MySQL.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 248
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.MySQL.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 248
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.SqlBuilder.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 249
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.SqlBuilder.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 249
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.MessageCollector.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 250
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.MessageCollector.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 250
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.ErrorManager.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 251
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.ErrorManager.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 251
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.ObjectFactory.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 252
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.ObjectFactory.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 252
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.StringManipulator.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 253
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.StringManipulator.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 253
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.Context.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 254
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.Context.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 254
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.Delegation.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 255
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Framework/Framework.Class.Delegation.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 255
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/Vanilla/Vanilla.Functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 256
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/Vanilla/Vanilla.Functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 256
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.Authenticator.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 257
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.Authenticator.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 257
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.Session.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 258
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.Session.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 258
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.PasswordHash.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 259
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.PasswordHash.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 259
Warning: include_once(/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.User.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 260
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/path/to/your/library/People/People.Class.User.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 260
Fatal error: Class 'Context' not found in /var/www/michebagshows.com/rep_forums/forums/appg/settings.php on line 262
```

Settings.php

```
<?php
/*
* Copyright 2003 Mark O'Sullivan
* This file is part of Vanilla.
* Vanilla is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
* Vanilla is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more details.
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with Vanilla; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
* The latest source code for Vanilla is available at www.lussumo.com
* Contact Mark O'Sullivan at mark [at] lussumo [dot] com
* Description: Global application constants
* ATTENTION: !DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN THIS FILE!
* If you wish to override any configuration setting, do it in the
* conf/settings.php file. This file will be overwritten when you apply upgrades
* to Vanilla. The conf/settings.php file will NOT be overwritten.
*/

ob_start();

$Configuration = array();

// Database Settings
$Configuration['DATABASE_SERVER'] = 'MySQL';
$Configuration['DATABASE_TABLE_PREFIX'] = 'LUM_';
$Configuration['DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost';
$Configuration['DATABASE_NAME'] = 'your_vanilla_database_name';
$Configuration['DATABASE_USER'] = 'your_vanilla_database_user_name';
$Configuration['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'your_vanilla_database_password';
$Configuration['FARM_DATABASE_HOST'] = '';
$Configuration['FARM_DATABASE_NAME'] = 'your_farm_database_name';
$Configuration['FARM_DATABASE_USER'] = 'your_farm_database_user_name';
$Configuration['FARM_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'your_farm_database_password';
$Configuration['DATABASE_CHARACTER_ENCODING'] = '';
$Configuration['DATABASE_VERSION'] = '1';

// Path Settings
$Configuration['APPLICATION_PATH'] = '/path/to/vanilla/';
$Configuration['DATABASE_PATH'] = '/path/to/your/database/file.php';
$Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/path/to/your/library/';
$Configuration['EXTENSIONS_PATH'] = '/path/to/your/extensions/';
$Configuration['LANGUAGES_PATH'] = '/path/to/your/languages/';
$Configuration['THEME_PATH'] = '/path/to/vanilla/themes/vanilla/';
$Configuration['BASE_URL'] = 'http://your.base.url/to/vanilla/';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_STYLE'] = '/vanilla/themes/vanilla/styles/default/';
$Configuration['WEB_ROOT'] = '/vanilla/';
$Configuration['SIGNIN_URL'] = 'people.php';
$Configuration['SIGNOUT_URL'] = 'people.php?PostBackAction=SignOutNow';

// People Settings
$Configuration['AUTHENTICATION_MODULE'] = 'People/People.Class.Authenticator.php';
$Configuration['AUTHENTICATION_CLASS'] = 'Authenticator';
$Configuration['SESSION_NAME'] = '';
$Configuration['COOKIE_USER_KEY'] = 'lussumocookieone';
$Configuration['COOKIE_VERIFICATION_KEY'] = 'lussumocookietwo';
$Configuration['SESSION_USER_IDENTIFIER'] = 'LussumoUserID';
$Configuration['COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = '.domain.com';
$Configuration['COOKIE_PATH'] = '/';
$Configuration['SUPPORT_EMAIL'] = 'support@domain.com';
$Configuration['SUPPORT_NAME'] = 'Support';
$Configuration['LOG_ALL_IPS'] = '0';
$Configuration['FORWARD_VALIDATED_USER_URL'] = './';
$Configuration['ALLOW_IMMEDIATE_ACCESS'] = '0';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_ROLE'] = '0';
$Configuration['APPROVAL_ROLE'] = '3';
$Configuration['SAFE_REDIRECT'] = 'people.php?PageAction=SignOutNow';
$Configuration['PEOPLE_USE_EXTENSIONS'] = '1';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_EMAIL_VISIBLE'] = '0';
$Configuration['PASSWORD_HASH_ITERATION'] = '8';
$Configuration['PASSWORD_HASH_PORTABLE'] = '1';

// Framework Settings
$Configuration['SMTP_HOST'] = '';
$Configuration['SMTP_USER'] = '';
$Configuration['SMTP_PASSWORD'] = '';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_EMAIL_MIME_TYPE'] = 'text/plain';
$Configuration['LANGUAGE'] = "English";
$Configuration['URL_BUILDING_METHOD'] = 'Standard';  // Standard or mod_rewrite
$Configuration['CHARSET'] = 'utf-8';
$Configuration['PAGE_EVENTS'] = array('Page_Init', 'Page_Render', 'Page_Unload');
$Configuration['PAGELIST_NUMERIC_TEXT'] = '0';
$Configuration['LIBRARY_NAMESPACE_ARRAY'] = array('Framework', 'People', 'Vanilla');
$Configuration['LIBRARY_INCLUDE_PATH'] = '%LIBRARY%';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_FORMAT_TYPE'] = 'Text';
$Configuration['FORMAT_TYPES'] = array('Text');
$Configuration['APPLICATION_TITLE'] = 'Vanilla';
$Configuration['BANNER_TITLE'] = 'Vanilla';
$Configuration['UPDATE_REMINDER'] = 'Monthly';
$Configuration['LAST_UPDATE'] = '';
$Configuration['HTTP_METHOD'] = 'http'; // Could alternately be https

// Vanilla Settings
$Configuration['ENABLE_WHISPERS'] = '0';
$Configuration['DISCUSSIONS_PER_PAGE'] = '30';
$Configuration['COMMENTS_PER_PAGE'] = '50';
$Configuration['SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE'] = '30';
$Configuration['ALLOW_NAME_CHANGE'] = '1';
$Configuration['ALLOW_EMAIL_CHANGE'] = '1';
$Configuration['ALLOW_PASSWORD_CHANGE'] = '1';
$Configuration['USE_REAL_NAMES'] = '1';
$Configuration['PUBLIC_BROWSING'] = '1';
$Configuration['USE_CATEGORIES'] = '1';
$Configuration['MAX_COMMENT_LENGTH'] = '5000';
$Configuration['MAX_TOPIC_WORD_LENGTH'] = '45';
$Configuration['DISCUSSION_POST_THRESHOLD'] = '3';
$Configuration['DISCUSSION_TIME_THRESHOLD'] = '60';
$Configuration['DISCUSSION_THRESHOLD_PUNISHMENT'] = '120';
$Configuration['COMMENT_POST_THRESHOLD'] = '5';
$Configuration['COMMENT_TIME_THRESHOLD'] = '60';
$Configuration['COMMENT_THRESHOLD_PUNISHMENT'] = '120';
$Configuration['UPDATE_URL'] = 'http://lussumo.com/updatecheck/default.php';

// Vanilla Control Positions
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_HEAD'] = '100';
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_MENU'] = '200';
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_BANNER'] = '200';
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_PANEL'] = '300';
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_NOTICES'] = '400';
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_BODY_ITEM'] = '500';
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_FOOT'] = '600';
$Configuration['CONTROL_POSITION_PAGE_END'] = '700';

// Vanilla Tab Positions
$Configuration['TAB_POSITION_DISCUSSIONS'] = '10';
$Configuration['TAB_POSITION_CATEGORIES'] = '20';
$Configuration['TAB_POSITION_SEARCH'] = '30';
$Configuration['TAB_POSITION_SETTINGS'] = '40';
$Configuration['TAB_POSITION_ACCOUNT'] = '50';

// Url Rewriting Definitions
$Configuration['REWRITE_categories.php'] = 'categories/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_index.php'] = 'discussions/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_comments.php'] = 'discussion/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_search.php'] = 'search/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_account.php'] = 'account/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_settings.php'] = 'settings/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_post.php'] = 'post/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_people.php'] = 'people/';
$Configuration['REWRITE_extension.php'] = 'extension/';

// Default values for role permissions
// Standard Permissions
$Configuration['PERMISSION_SIGN_IN'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_ADD_COMMENTS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_START_DISCUSSION'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_HTML_ALLOWED'] = '0';
// Discussion Moderator Permissions
$Configuration['PERMISSION_SINK_DISCUSSIONS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_STICK_DISCUSSIONS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_HIDE_DISCUSSIONS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_CLOSE_DISCUSSIONS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_EDIT_DISCUSSIONS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_VIEW_HIDDEN_DISCUSSIONS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_EDIT_COMMENTS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_HIDE_COMMENTS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_VIEW_HIDDEN_COMMENTS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_ADD_COMMENTS_TO_CLOSED_DISCUSSION'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_ADD_CATEGORIES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_EDIT_CATEGORIES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_REMOVE_CATEGORIES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_SORT_CATEGORIES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_VIEW_ALL_WHISPERS'] = '0';
// User Moderator Permissions
$Configuration['PERMISSION_APPROVE_APPLICANTS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_RECEIVE_APPLICATION_NOTIFICATION'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_CHANGE_USER_ROLE'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_EDIT_USERS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_IP_ADDRESSES_VISIBLE'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_MANAGE_REGISTRATION'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_SORT_ROLES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_ADD_ROLES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_EDIT_ROLES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_REMOVE_ROLES'] = '0';
// Administrative Permissions
$Configuration['PERMISSION_CHECK_FOR_UPDATES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_CHANGE_APPLICATION_SETTINGS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_MANAGE_EXTENSIONS'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_MANAGE_LANGUAGE'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_MANAGE_THEMES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_MANAGE_STYLES'] = '0';
$Configuration['PERMISSION_ALLOW_DEBUG_INFO'] = '0';

// Default values for User Preferences
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_HtmlOn'] = '1';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_ShowAppendices'] = '1';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_ShowSavedSearches'] = '1';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_ShowTextToggle'] = '1';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_JumpToLastReadComment'] = '1';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_ShowLargeCommentBox'] = '0';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_ShowFormatSelector'] = '1';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_ShowDeletedDiscussions'] = '0';
$Configuration['PREFERENCE_ShowDeletedComments'] = '0';

// Newbie settings
// Has Vanilla been installed (this will be set to true in conf/settings.php when setup completes)
$Configuration['SETUP_COMPLETE'] = '0';
$Configuration['ADDON_NOTICE'] = '1';

// Application versions
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/version.php');

// Application Mode Constants
define('MODE_DEBUG', 'DEBUG');
define('MODE_RELEASE', 'RELEASE');

// Format type definitions
define('FORMAT_STRING_FOR_DISPLAY', 'DISPLAY');
define('FORMAT_STRING_FOR_DATABASE', 'DATABASE');

// PHP Settings
define('MAGIC_QUOTES_ON', get_magic_quotes_gpc());

// Self Url (should be hard-coded by each page - this is here just in case it was forgotten)
$Configuration['SELF_URL'] = @$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// Include custom settings
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../conf/settings.php');
if ($Configuration['SETUP_COMPLETE'] == '0') {
    header('Location: ./setup/index.php');
}

// Define a constant to prevent a register_globals attack on the configuration paths
define('IN_VANILLA', '1');

//upgrade database
if ($Configuration['DATABASE_VERSION'] < 2) {
    include_once($Configuration['APPLICATION_PATH'].'appg/database.php');
    include_once($Configuration['DATABASE_PATH']);
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Functions.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.Database.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.'.$Configuration['DATABASE_SERVER'].'.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.SqlBuilder.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.MessageCollector.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.ErrorManager.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.ObjectFactory.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.StringManipulator.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.Context.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Framework/Framework.Class.Delegation.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'Vanilla/Vanilla.Functions.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].$Configuration['AUTHENTICATION_MODULE']);
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'People/People.Class.Session.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'People/People.Class.PasswordHash.php');
    include_once($Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'].'People/People.Class.User.php');

    $Context = new Context($Configuration);
    $Context->DatabaseTables = &$DatabaseTables;
    $Context->DatabaseColumns = &$DatabaseColumns;  

    $Query = 'ALTER TABLE '
        . GetTableName('User', $DatabaseTables, $Configuration["DATABASE_TABLE_PREFIX"])
        . ' CHANGE ' . $DatabaseColumns['User']['Password'].' '
        . $DatabaseColumns['User']['Password'] . ' VARBINARY( 34 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL';
    if ($Context->Database->Execute($Query,'','','',0)) {
        AddConfigurationSetting($Context, 'DATABASE_VERSION', '2');
    }
    unset($Context, $Query);
}

?>
```

conf/settings.php

```
<?php
// Application Settings
$Configuration['SETUP_TEST'] = '1';
$Configuration['APPLICATION_PATH'] = '/var/www/michebagshows.com/vanilla/';
$Configuration['DATABASE_PATH'] = '/var/www/michebagshows.com/vanilla/conf/database.php';
$Configuration['LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/var/www/michebagshows.com/vanilla/library/';
$Configuration['EXTENSIONS_PATH'] = '/var/www/michebagshows.com/vanilla/extensions/';
$Configuration['LANGUAGES_PATH'] = '/var/www/michebagshows.com/vanilla/languages/';
$Configuration['THEME_PATH'] = '/var/www/michebagshows.com/vanilla/themes/Blogger/';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_STYLE'] = '/themes/Blogger/styles/default/';
$Configuration['WEB_ROOT'] = '/';
$Configuration['BASE_URL'] = 'http://forums.michebagshows.com/';
$Configuration['FORWARD_VALIDATED_USER_URL'] = 'http://forums.michebagshows.com/';
$Configuration['SUPPORT_EMAIL'] = 'info@michebag.com';
$Configuration['SUPPORT_NAME'] = 'Miche Bag';
$Configuration['APPLICATION_TITLE'] = 'Miche Bag Distributor Forums';
$Configuration['BANNER_TITLE'] = 'Distributor Forums';
$Configuration['COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = 'forums.michebagshows.com';
$Configuration['COOKIE_PATH'] = '/';
$Configuration['SETUP_COMPLETE'] = '1';
$Configuration['DATABASE_VERSION'] = '2';
$Configuration['ADDON_NOTICE'] = '0';
$Configuration['SMTP_USER'] = 'admin';
$Configuration['SMTP_PASSWORD'] = 'm1ch3b4g';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_ROLE'] = '3';
$Configuration['ALLOW_IMMEDIATE_ACCESS'] = '1';
$Configuration['NOTIFI_ALLOW_ALL'] = '1';
$Configuration['NOTIFI_ALLOW_DISCUSSION'] = '1';
$Configuration['NOTIFI_ALLOW_CATEGORY'] = '1';
$Configuration['NOTIFI_AUTO_ALL'] = '0';
$Configuration['NOTIFI_INSTALL_V2_COMPLETE'] = '1';
$Configuration['PASSWORD_RESET_VERSION'] = '0.3';
$Configuration['LAST_UPDATE'] = '1265210955';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_PAGE_USE_RETURN'] = '';
$Configuration['DEFAULT_PAGE'] = 'categories.php';
$Configuration['PUBLIC_BROWSING'] = '0';
$Configuration['ATTACHMENTS_UPLOAD_PATH'] = '/var/www/michebagshows.com/vanilla/uploads/%year%/%month%/';
$Configuration['ATTACHMENTS_MAXIMUM_FILESIZE'] = '3512000';
$Configuration['ATTACHMENTS_VERSION'] = '2.1';
?>
```

Comment: Looks like `settings.php` has reverted to some kind of default state, since all the paths are prefixed with `/path/to/your` - can you post the contents of the file here?

Comment: Has your hosting company recently made any changes? Are all files that are being included present?

Comment: Dave, that could be it. What do you mean by the contents? As in the files being included?

CodeCaster, I'll have to check back on the hosting company, but the files are all present.

Comment: @ElliPetersen if you download the `settings.php` file from your host and open it in a text editor, then click the "edit" button under your question and copy and paste the text here, on the bottom of the existing text. The text should start with `<?php` or possibly just `<?`

Comment: @DaveRandom There you go, sorry about the wait.

Comment: @ElliPetersen Yep that's one default configuration file by the looks of things, and to be honest it's going to be hard for anyone here to help you correct it. It looks like you need to run through some kind of installation process (because, for one thing, of the line `$Configuration['SETUP_COMPLETE'] = '0';`, which basically says "setup not complete"). I suspect this is the fault of your hosting company, and with any luck they'll have a backup of the correct version of this file - but there are far too many settings there for us to be able to work out how to fix it blind.

Comment: @ElliPetersen actually, looking at it, it may be the case that the file `conf/settings.php` is missing or corrupt - can you find this file? It seems as though something has possibly been upgraded, because all the code that causes the errors you see is related to upgrading the database.

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes, it's there. I've added it to the OP.

Comment: @ElliPetersen can you please add this line to `Settings.php` (the first one you posted): immediately after the line `define('IN_VANILLA', '1');` please add `var_dump($Configuration);`. Once you have done this, put the file back on the server in the right place, and the output should change when you load the page (hopefully) with some information that may help

Comment: @ElliPetersen Make sure you keep a backup of any files that you change!!!

Comment: @DaveRandom I've added the line but I'm not able to replace the file; another admin has control of the folder. We're trying to contact him. I'll check up when we're able to...

Comment: @ElliPetersen What matters is that `conf/settings.php` does not seem to be loaded correctly - the necessary settings are all present in that file, and they should be loaded at the line `include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../conf/settings.php');` but this is not happening correctly. It seems odd that this is not throwing an error to tell you that, but this is what appears to be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found out what the problem was... It turns out our old programmer didn't transfer the rest of the files over to the right server. I wasn't even aware there was a transfer. But it's fixed now! Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@DaveRandom is right. Your config file (settings.php) has been overwritten or backed up from a state that is not configured, but it is a mystery to me how this could have happened by accident.

The proof is right here, and indicates that the forum doesn't think it has been configured yet:

```
$Configuration['SETUP_COMPLETE'] = '0';
```

Perhaps someone reinstalled the Vanilla software, or tried to perform some kind of update, and accidentally overwrote this important file.

settings.php usually contains all the site-specific configuration for your forum, such as database names and passwords, the root folders of your site's various applications, etc. This is the kind of thing that is built at setup time, when you first install your forum.

Unless you have a backup of this file, you're going to have to perform the setup again. Make sure you backup your database first.

Comment: So we found out what the problem was... It turns out our old programmer didn't transfer the rest of the files over to the right server. I wasn't even aware there was a transfer. But it's fixed now! Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @Elli Petersen - Don't forget to mark answers as the answer! It's the checkbox outline to the left of the response.